# Are there any known compatibility issues with Microsoft Media Platform: Player Framework (formerly SMF) and Silverlight 5?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, mmppf

I'm trying to get the default template (adaptive streaming) for the MMPPF framework to work.
Currently I'm not getting any error, but the player does not play any videos. I've tried adding other sources besides the default, I can see them added in the playlist, but they won't play either.

Using Fiddler I can see that the player does not even attempt to retrieve the manifest (or anything else).
The online example [here](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/content/smf/howto/v2/examples/EmbedSmoothStreamingPlayer/EmbedSmoothStreamingPlayer.html) works fine, I've even tried using that manifest as a source, but it still won't play when I run it in Visual studio.

So my question, could this have anything to do with having Silverlight 5 toolkit installed? I would assume that the MMPPF/SMF template is supposed to work out of the box (which is also stated on the Codeplex site). Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add some references to your project. MMPPF is using MEF to resolve plugins at run-time, and it can fail silently if it doesn't find a suitable plugin.

For Smooth Streaming, you need both `Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.SmoothStreaming` and `Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming` for it to work for instance.

---

Update:

I've encountered another reference issue when migrating a project. I had to remove and re-add System.ComponentModel.Composition, then add System.ComponentModel.Composition.Initialization.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But I'm using the MMPPF default template, and it already have all the references added.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to uninstall the Smooth Streaming Client that the MMPPF client installed and installed the newest from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8227), added a reference to the new dll (Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.dll) and everything worked.

Comment: Ah, so it was a reference problem after all :)

Comment: hehe, I suppose. I'll give you the answer ;)